# Applying rotation matrices from Open3D to objects in IFC OpenShell

Tags: open3d, rotational-matrices, bim, transformation-matrix, ifc-open-shell

I'm working on a project where I need to apply rotation matrices obtained from Open3D to objects represented in IFC OpenShell. As per the documentations for the two: in Open3D, the rotation matrix represents rotation relative to the object's center, while in IFC OpenShell, rotation is defined based on two vectors: the local X axis and the local Z axis vector. I'm facing challenges in reconciling these differences and correctly applying the rotations.

Could someone provide guidance or code examples on how to convert rotation matrices from Open3D to the representation expected by IFC OpenShell, and how to apply these rotations to objects in IFC OpenShell?

Right now I am using the below code to extract the rotation matrix for a point cloud and then using the obtained parameters to create a wall like representation in IFC Open Shell. Here we're writing the rotation matrix to a txt file for simplicity.

In Open3D:

```
# Code to extract the rotation matrix from the point cloud and save it in a file.
obb = point_cloud.get_oriented_bounding_box()
rotation_matrix = obb.R
min_x, min_y, min_z = obb.get_min_bound()
transformation_matrix = np.hstack((rotation_matrix, np.array([[min_x], [min_y], [min_z]])))
length = obb.extent[0]
width = obb.extent[1]
height = obb.extent[2]

f.write(f"{length}, {width}, {height}, ")
f.write(", ".join(map(str, transformation_matrix.flatten())))
f.write("\n")
```

In IFC OpenShell:

```
wall = run("root.create_entity", model, ifc_class="IfcWall")
run("geometry.edit_object_placement", model, product=wall, matrix=transformation_matrix)
representation = run("geometry.add_wall_representation", model, context=body, length=length, height=height, thickness=0.5)
run("geometry.assign_representation", model, product=wall, representation=representation)
run("spatial.assign_container", model, relating_structure=storey, product=wall)
```

Where:
matrix: 4x4 transformation matrix for object placement
length: Length of the wall
height: Height of the wall
thickness: Thickness of the wall

References:

1. [Open 3D - Get Oriented Bounding Box rotate method](https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.OrientedBoundingBox.html#open3d.geometry.OrientedBoundingBox.rotate)
2. [IFC Open Shell - Object Placements](https://blenderbim.org/docs-python/ifcopenshell-python/geometry_creation.html#object-placements)
3. [Open3D Rotation](https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Basic/transformation.html#Rotation)